# What is the best way to schedule tasks in a serverless stack?

Tags: firebase, amazon-ec2, next.js, serverless

I am using NextJS and Firebase for an application. The users are able to rent products for a certain period. After that period, a serverless function should be triggered which updates the database etc. Since NextJS is event-driven I cannot seem to figured out how to schedule a task, which executes when the rental period ends and the database is updated.

Perhaps cron jobs handled elsewhere (Easy Cron etc) are a solution. Or maybe an EC2 instance just for scheduling these tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is marked with AWS EC2, i've assumed it's ok to suggest a solution with AWS services in mind.

What you could do is leverage DynamoDB's speed & sort capabilities. If you specify a table with both the partition key and the range key, the data is automatically sorted in the UTF-8 order. This means iso-timestamp values can be used to sort data historically.

With this in mind, you could design your table to have a partition key of a global, constant value across all users (to group them all) and a sort key of `isoDate#userId`, while also creating an GSI (Global Secondary Index) with the userId as the partition key, and the isoDate as the range key.

With your data sorted, you can use the BETWEEN query to extract the entries that fit to your time window.

Schedule 1 lambda to run every minute (or so) and extract the entries that are about to expire to notify them about it.

**Important note**: This sorting method works when ALL range keys **have the same size**, due to how sorting with the UTF-8 works. You can easily accomplish this if your application uses UUIDs as ids. If not, you can simply generate a random UUID to attach to the isoTimestamp, as you only need it to avoid the rare exact time duplicity.

Example: lets say you want to extract all data from expiring near the 2022-10-10T12:00:00.000Z hour:

your query would be `BETWEEN 2022-10-10T11:59:00.000Z#00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 and 2022-10-10T12:00:59.999Z#zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz`

Timestamps could be a little off, but you get the idea. 00.. is the start UTF8 of an UUID, and zz.. (or fff..) is the end.

Answer (score -1):

In AWS creating periodic triggers to Lambda using AWS Console is quite simple and straight-forward.

```
Login to console and navigate to CloudWatch.
Under Events, select Rules & click “Create Rule”
You can either select fixed rate or select Cron Expression for more control
Cron expression in CloudWatch starts from minutes not seconds, important to remember if you are copying Cron expression from somewhere else.
Click “Add Target”, select “Lambda Function” from drop down & then select appropriate Lambda function.
If you want to pass some data to the target function when triggered, you can do so by expanding “Configure Input”
```

Comment: periodic triggers seem fairly simple. I am thinking more of scheduling a trigger exactly at a predefined time. for example, a user's rental period ends at 1:00pm and I want to notify them exactly 5 minutes before. How do I schedule a function to trigger exactly at 12:55pm?